# How to arrange content in single excel cell, while there is more than 2 paragraphs and lot of space

Tags: microsoft-excel

[I need to make content like cell B3 but default paragraphs are like B2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/joK6X.png)

Answer (score 1):

You need to do two things:

1. insert hard returns in the text where you want the breaks to occur *(these are ASCII-10's)*
2. format the cells with `Wrap` on

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

If you are directly typing text into the cells, then the easiest way to insert the hard returns is to touch <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: I believe OP wants to remove the line breaks.